# Is there any way to suppress the "incompatible accessory" warning on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, accessories

Every time I connect my iPhone to the dock in my vehicle, the following warning message is displayed:

[image]

After dismissing the warning dialog, everything appears to works fine. Is there any way to suppress this dialog from being displayed **every** time I connect my iPhone to the dock?

(Enabling Airplane Mode does seem to do the trick, but that's not a realistic solution as I don't want to lose voice/data functionality when docking the iPhone.)

Answer (score 1):

Gotta be jailbroken AFAIK. There's a package called [Popup Blocker](http://modmyi.com/cydia/package.php?id=10595) that suppresses alerts. This is probably the best option.

I recommend [Spirit](http://spiritjb.com/) for jailbreaking 3.1.2 or 3.1.3. It's super easy and works well for everyday (non-hacker) use.